# Virtual host on Windows 10 with Apache 2.4

Tags: windows, apache, virtual-machine

Can you tell me please what am I doing wrong in Virtual host settings?
I am editing two files: 
Apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts

httpd-vhosts.conf looks like

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   ServerName scouttautomotive.com
   ServerAlias www.scouttautomotive.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/scouttautomotive/web"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   ServerName bosp.sk
   ServerAlias bosp.sk.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/bosp/web"
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file looks like

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1 scouttautomotive.com
127.0.0.1 bosp.sk
```

What is wrong with it? I am realy confused cause bosp.sk virtual host works well.

Comment: This config files should be ok, BUT look at my own answer of this question.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the domain ip to 127.0.0.1 to host file, You must restart your computer or flush dns cache to get that applied. Did you do?

Comment: I did restart Apache and then whole computer. How can I flush dns cache?

Comment: I try to flush the cache like http://www.technipages.com/flush-and-reset-the-dns-resolver-cache-using-ipconfig but nochange.

Comment: Which software are you using (i.e. WAMP, XAMPP)? Can you show your httpd-vhosts.conf  file?

Comment: I am on my own installation(no Wamp...). httpd-vhosts.conf is in the question(??? Everything in there is commented + NameVirtualHost is removed).

Comment: It is completely insane. I made another virtual which leads to the same folder and it works. What the hell is going on? ServerName drom.com DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/scouttautomotive/web"

Comment: look at he answer I made to this question.

Answer (score 0):

So look at these config files and note that difference is only in the last letter of ServerName.

httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   ServerName scouttautomotive.com
   ServerAlias scout.com.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/scouttautomotive/web"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
   ServerName scouttautomotiv.com
   ServerAlias drom.com.localhost
   DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24/htdocs/scouttautomotive/web"
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts

```
127.0.0.1 scouttautomotive.com
127.0.0.1 scouttautomotiv.com
```

First version redirects me to one hosting which offers this domain to sell. Second version works well as virtual host. Both are created in the same time. So it looks command **ipconfig /flushdns** may not be enough.

Another possible solutions can be find here https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot Good luck!